# How can I access elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with getting data from JSON array.

Here is the JSON code:

```
[
  [
    4.440216064453125,
    [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1],
    0,
    "Test0",
    "Test0",
    [129]
  ],
  [
    4.452216148376465,
    [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    1,
    "Test1",
    "Test1",
    [1,0,0]
  ]
]
```

And i want to alert "1" value. It is "Test1".

Here is JS code:

```
function inspect(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'addtest.json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(JSON) {
            alert(JSON.array[1])
        },

        error: function(JSON) {
            alert("Error")
        }
    });
}
```

It's not working properly.

Could you please help ?

Comment: "It's not working properly" does not give any idea to what is wrong. Can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: That's some really awkward JSON. Is that what is being returned?

Answer (score 1):

`JSON` is an defined object in JavaScript, use another variable

```
function inspect(){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'addtest.json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response[1][3]);   // For showing "Test1"
        },

        error: function(err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry had to wait few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The outer level of your JSON data consists of an array.

You are treating it as an object with a property *named* `array`.

Also, don't call your argument `JSON`, you'll make the (useful) `JSON` object that is built into browsers.

`Test1` is a value of an array that is a member of an array that is a member of the outer most array. You can access it by drilling down through each array in turn.

```
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[1][3])
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this it will help you to access array.
Comment shows the position of element in array.

```
[
  [
    4.440216064453125,  // <- [0][0]
    [
        1, // <- [0][1][0]
        0, // <- [0][1][1]
        0, // <- [0][1][2]
        0, // <- [0][1][3]
        1, // <- [0][1][4]
        1, // <- [0][1][5]
        1, // <- [0][1][6]
        0, // <- [0][1][7]
        0, // <- [0][1][8]
        1, // <- [0][1][9]
        1 // <- [0][1][10]
    ], // <- [0][1]
    0,// <- [0][2]
    "Test0",// <- [0][3]
    "Test0",// <- [0][4]
    [129]// <- [0][5]
  ], // <- [0]
  [
    4.452216148376465,// <- [1][0]
    [
        1, // <- [1][1][0]
        0, // <- [1][1][1]
        0, // <- [1][1][2]
        0, // <- [1][1][3]
        1, // <- [1][1][4]
        1, // <- [1][1][5]
        1, // <- [1][1][6]
        1, // <- [1][1][7]
        1, // <- [1][1][8]
        0, // <- [1][1][9]
        0 // <- [1][1][10]
    ],// <- [1][1]
    1,// <- [1][2]
    "Test1",// <- [1][3]
    "Test1",// <- [1][4]
    [1,0,0]// <- [1][5]
  ] // <- [1]
]
```